# ggplot2 - Legend is not appearing

Tags: r, ggplot2

A legend is supposed to show up automatically with ggplot2, but it won't appear. Here is my code.

`` ggplot(data = StudentsPerformance, aes(`math score`)) + geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1) + geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, aes(`reading score`), fill = "green") + geom_dotplot(binwidth = 1, aes(`writing score`), fill = "red") ``

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide a `dput()` of your data.

Comment: Legends show up automatically for mapped values, i.e. what you put into the `aes()` function. Setting `fill = "green"` doesn't make a legend show up, it is more typical to set `aes(..., colour = "this_is_what_my_green_line_means")` and then setup a (manual) scale setting the colour for that to green.